# How to install Processing using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, processing

I want to install processing via maven in intellij. I have added the following to my POM file:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.processing</groupId>
    <artifactId>processing-complete</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.7</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When trying to build, it says Cannot resolve `org.processing:processing-complete:3.3.7`

However, the file is definitely there in the repository: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/processing/processing-complete/3.3.7/

anyone has any idea how to successfully build the complete processing library using maven or gradle?

PS. I am a huge noob with maven, so it might be something simple, but I've tried a bunch of stuff and nothing seems to work.

Edited to have the maven log: from mvn -X dependency:sources

https://gist.github.com/jurrejelle/91b59785c7a3184e776f0a1797c416f4

Comment: Please, posto your maven log.

Answer (score 3):

Your dependency section is asking for a jar file (the default type), which isn't present in the artifact.  If you look on [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.processing/processing-complete/3.3.7/pom), you can see that the given dependency tag includes a `pom` type tag:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.processing</groupId>
  <artifactId>processing-complete</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.7</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

I was able to reproduce your error using the XML you posted, and adding `<type>pom</type>` in my pom.xml cleared up the error for me.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't give an error for me anymore, but it doesn't actually let me install it either

[INFO] The following files have NOT been resolved:
[INFO]    org.processing:processing-complete:pom:sources:3.3.7:compile

Comment: Oops, my bad, forgot to add my new log: https://gist.github.com/jurrejelle/a875d8e9ab1bdbfcc07c20c93c6a0d37

Comment: Sure, processing-complete doesn't have any actual code in it, so you aren't going to be able to compile it.  Are you sure you aren't missing some other dependency such as processing-core? (p.s. you might want to ask a follow-up question about the actual "getting it to run" issue).